# ReactJS - To run the function state getting set on second click

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to display my `autoForm` component as child within the `Modal` (parent pop-up) component.

The issue I am facing is, while rendering the `Modal` it displays the `autoForm` component with all the required fields but not displaying the field values in it.

While on second click it displays the field values. the fields state is not getting set at first click and that's why the data not getting displayed. Not sure why the state is not getting set at first click.

-- the `autoForm` component : -

```
    export default class ActivityForm extends React.Component<IActivityFormProps> {
  render() {
    const { fieldValues = {}, moduleName, onSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <AutoForm
        customOnly
        moduleName={moduleName}
        fieldValues={fieldValues}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {({ fields, createField, addProps, renderSubmit, group }) => {
          return (
            <Flex fill center alignCenter>
              {fields.activityRecord && fields.activityRecord.length > 0
                ? fields.activityRecord.map((activity, index) => {
                    const { time, type, note } = activity;

                    return (
                      <Flex key={index} center column alignCenter>
                        {group([
                          addProps(time, {
                            label: 'Date',
                          }),
                          type,
                        ])}
                        {group([note])}
                        {renderSubmit()}
                      </Flex>
                    );
                  })
                : null}
            </Flex>
          );
        }}
      </AutoForm>
    );
  }
}
```

The Modal component : -

```
export default class ActivityEdit extends React.Component<IEditActivityProps> {
    activityRecord[activity] = data;
    activityRecord['callback'] = callback;
    onClose();
    onUpdate(activityRecord);
  }

  render() {
    const { item, active, activity, onClose } = this.props;
    const { activityRecord = [], _id = '' } = item || {};
    const activityFields = [activityRecord[activity]];

    return (
      <Modal
        active={active}
        onClose={onClose}
        onGoBack={onClose}
        title={'Edit Activity'}
      >
        <Form
          fieldValues={{ activityRecord: activityFields, _id }}
          moduleName={'clientUsers'}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: From your code it looks like `activityRecord` is an array, but you are using it as a key in `fieldValues={{ activityRecord: activityFields, _id }}`? and not sure what you are trying to do with `_id`. Can you explain that object and what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: Oh maybe that's a dynamic bracket notation?

Comment: yes, 'activityRecord' is an array of object which specifically contains the only single object. and that is passed to 'AutoForm' component.
Specifically, the 'AutoForm' component fetches the field's value and sets the state of same fields data to display from 'componentWillReceiveProps' method.

Comment: the state is not getting set at the first click of button event and displaying empty fields, but at the same time get set at second click successfully and data gets displayed in respective fields.